# Invalid MEX-file error CascadeClassifier_.mexmaci64, libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib

Tags: macos, matlab, opencv, shared-libraries, mex

I am on OSX  10.10. 
I am trying to run a demo of a project which uses the following libraries and programs:

- MATLAB R2014b 64-bit.
- OpenCV 2.4.10.1 installed through Homebrew.
- VLFeat 0.9.20.
- mexopencv.

I have run `mex -setup` in MATLAB which sets the compiler to clang.

The path of VLFeat and mexopencv have been added in the `startup.m` file in MATLAB.

When I try to run `demo_test.m` file I get the following errors in MATLAB:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/Users/maverick/Documents/Project/mexopencv-master/+cv/private/CascadeClassifier_.mexmaci64':
dlopen(/Users/maverick/Documents/Project/mexopencv-master/+cv/private/CascadeClassifier_.mexmaci64, 6): Symbol not found:
__ZN2cv3ocl12getOclMatRefERKNS_11_InputArrayE
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.dylib
  Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/maci64/libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.dylib

Error in cv.CascadeClassifier (line 33)
            this.id = CascadeClassifier_(filename);

Error in faceAlign (line 8)
    detector = cv.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml');


Error in regressionFit (line 11)
            [shape, rat, ~, init_s] = faceAlign(img, [], [], R{round_number}, b{round_number}, [], pad, [1:66], 0);


Error in demo_test (line 16)
shape = regressionFit(img, [], R, b);
```

I know the project works because I have tried it on another computer.
How do I resolve this error and get the project to run? Thanks.

EDIT 1:
This is the output when I run otool -L (equivalent of ldd)...

```
    $ otool -L /Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/maci64/libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib

/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/maci64/libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib:
    @rpath/libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
    @rpath/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
    @rpath/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
    @rpath/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
    @rpath/libtbb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

EDIT 2: 
This is the output of otool -L on CascadeClassifier_.mexmaci64

```
$ otool -L Documents/Project/mexopencv-master/+cv/private/CascadeClassifier_.mexmaci64
Documents/Project/mexopencv-master/+cv/private/CascadeClassifier_.mexmaci64:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 20.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.10)
    @rpath/libmx.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libmex.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libmat.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Am I missing some library? Is the PATH not configured correctly ?

Comment: clearly missing this symbol __ZN2cv3ocl12getOclMatRefERKNS_11_InputArrayE.  could be that a dylib is missing or is not pathed properly.

Comment: Look for the opencv ocl library.  But in general you can run `ldd mexfilw.asdf` outside if MATLAB and set `LD_RUN_PATH`.

Comment: @chappjc : I installed OpenCV library from Homebrew

Comment: @no10downingstreet that doesn't mean the mex file can find it.  Just look for the file yourself

Comment: @chappjc : I didn't understand what you said, sorry. I am on OSX. ldd runs on Linux. Could you please elaborate a little, I'm new to this.

Comment: Search your filesystem for a file like libopencv*.dynlib with ocl or opencl in the file name. Not sure if it starts with libopencv or just opencv. I don't have a Mac.

Comment: Try the `ldd` system command first so you know the exact name of the file you need to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab comes bundled with its own computer vision libraries. So it tries to use them first, even if you have OpenCV installed.

The solution is to move those bundled libraries to another folder (for backup in case something goes wrong) and then sym link the actual OpenCV libraries to the location previously populated by the bundled libraries.

If, after doing this, you get any error, then it is probably because Matlab is using its own library again. Do the same process again for this library too.